# Make animated GIF of construction steps in GeoGebra

Tags: javascript, geogebra

I am trying to make an animated GIF in GeoGebra of construction steps.  Note that it's not enough just to have a slider or to play the construction steps in the Construction Protocol because I want an animation that I can embed in other applications.

Just to learn the very basics, I am trying to do a minimal example.  So in the Algebra view I entered the following:

```
A=(0,1)
B=(0,2)
C=(0,3)
constList = {A,B,C}
stepSlider = Slider(0,2,1,1,200,false,true,false,false)
console = Text("blank")
```

I know that it's possible to go to each object, `A`, `B`, and `C`, and give it a condition to make visible.  However I would have to do that for each object, and if I do a construction with 50 objects, that will get really unpleasant so I want to try to find a more general scripting solution.

So to try to solve this, I then went into the slider properties, to the `Script` tag, to the `On Update` box.  I don't see a way to iterate over a list of elements in ggbScript so I switch over to JavaScript.  I then enter the following code

```
var step = ggbApplet.getValue("stepSlider");

ggbApplet.setTextValue("console",step); // just to see if it's getting the value correctly
// The the "console" does not get updated text when I run the slider, but I'm probably using this wrong.

var obj = ggbApplet.getValue("constList")[step];
var objName = ggbApplet.getObjectName(obj);
ggbApplet.setVisible(objName,true);
```

When I click play on the slider, nothing happens.  I was hoping that as the slider hits different values, it would display the points `A`, `B`, `C`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `console = Text("blank")` -> `console = "blank"`, then `ggbApplet.setTextValue()` will work.
2. `ggbApplet.getValue()` only return a double value, not a list. Use `ggbApplet.getAllObjectNames()` instead.
3. JS code:

```
var step = ggbApplet.getValue("stepSlider");
ggbApplet.setTextValue("console",step+"");
var obj = ggbApplet.getAllObjectNames()[step];
ggbApplet.setVisible(obj,true);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31958930)

Comment: Got it. Now I provided an answer.